# How to stop dolphin from updating file access times

Tags: files, filesystems, kde, timestamps, dolphin

I would like to utilize access times as an indicator to figure out which files I am actually still using. But whenever i view a directory in dolphin, the access timestamps of many of the contained files are updated, even without me actually opening any files. I have disabled previews in an effort to stop it but to no avail.

Whether or not specific files' timestamps are updated seems to depend on their extensions.

```
$ touch -at 202001010000 test.out test.m4a test.ogg test.txt
```

and after i open the directory in dolphin:

```
$ ls -lhu                                                                                
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 motersen users 0 Jan  1  2020 test.m4a
-rw-r--r-- 1 motersen users 0 Mar 31 11:30 test.ogg
-rw-r--r-- 1 motersen users 0 Mar 31 11:30 test.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 motersen users 0 Jan  1  2020 test.txt
```

This happens on a btrfs volume with relatime

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?